# Scanner reading File - nextLine()

Tags: java, file

I have a problem with the assignment. Basically the method `printLinesWhichContain(String word)` should print the lines that contain the given word, which works fine, and if the String is empty (`""`), print all lines in the file. The last part doesn't work. Any advice?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Printer {
    private File lol;
    private Scanner reader;

    public Printer(String fileName)throws Exception{
        this.lol = new File(fileName);
        this.reader = new Scanner(lol);
    }

    public void printLinesWhichContain(String word) {
        if (word.isEmpty()) {
            while (this.reader.hasNextLine()) {
                String x = this.reader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(x);
            }

        } else {
            while (this.reader.hasNextLine()) {
                String x = this.reader.nextLine();
                if (x.contains(word)) {
                    System.out.println(x);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Printer printer = new Printer("src/textfile.txt");

    printer.printLinesWhichContain("Väinämöinen");
    System.out.println("-----");
    printer.printLinesWhichContain("Frank Zappa");
    System.out.println("-----");
    printer.printLinesWhichContain("");
    System.out.println("-----");
    }
}
```

File text

```
Siinä vanha Väinämöinen
katseleikse käänteleikse 
Niin tuli kevätkäkönen
näki koivun kasvavaksi 
Miksipä on tuo jätetty
koivahainen kaatamatta  
Sanoi vanha Väinämöinen
```

Output

```
Siinä vanha Väinämöinen
Sanoi vanha Väinämöinen 
-----
-----
-----
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application you created only one Scanner which can iterate over entire file only once. If you want to iterate over entire file each time you invoke `printLinesWhichContain` method, you need to *reset* your scanner, most likely by creating new one.

So one of options would be reinitializing already *used* scanner at the end of

```
public void printLinesWhichContain(String word) {
    //...your original code

    this.reader = new Scanner(lol);
}
```

method. But if you don't use scanner elsewhere outside of this method maybe it may be worth making it local variable instead of class field.

```
public void printLinesWhichContain(String word) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(lol);

    //...your original code
}
```

---

Other option could be reading file once and storing its content, using code like

```
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(lol.toPath());
```

You can iterate over this list instead of file.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `main` to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Printer printer = new Printer("src/textfile.txt");

    printer.printLinesWhichContain("Väinämöinen");
    System.out.println("-----");
    printer.printLinesWhichContain("Frank Zappa");
    System.out.println("-----");
    printer = new Printer("src/textfile.txt");

    printer.printLinesWhichContain("");
    System.out.println("-----");
}
```

It will work. Reason being that, due to the way you've written your code, `printer` needs to be reinitialized so that it can start reading from the beginning again.